# Arrange sorting type of asc in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a data in my database like this:
`0 1 2 1 0 3` and i want to sort it ascending and the 1st record should be 1 not the 0. I want an output like this:
`1 1 2 3 0 0`.
Please any one help me? i have a stored procedure like this:

```
select * from table order by number ascending
```

and the output is `0 0 1 1 2 3`

anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from table order by CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN 999999 ELSE id END
```

This simply changes the sort order and is easily extensible if you want to add extra fields.

Comment: nice hack... However watch out that no number in your table is higher than 'THEN 999999'

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple .You can select twice with where condition and use union all.

```
select * into #temp from table where id <> 0 order by id

select * from #temp
union all
select * from table where id = 0
```

Comment: union all is not working if there is an order by keyword/syntax

Comment: You can copy that data to temp table and then perform union all

Comment: thanks to your help. it works but i should go for the shorter one. hehe.